# Unable to Replace SSH KeyFile and SSH_Username With Variables in Bash Script

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-agent

I am on ubuntu 20.04 and I am running a bash script that I want to make portable to my other servers, but I can't replace the identityfile AND the ssh_username with variables, at the same time, without getting a pubkey error.

First I used `shellcheck.net` to verify that my basic syntax is correct

```
#!/bin/bash
source_ssh_user="admin"
source_ssh_host="123.456.789.12"
connecting_keyfile="/home/username/.ssh/id_my_rsa"


#this does NOT work, but it should:

ssh -i $connecting_keyfile $source_ssh_user@$source_ssh_host
```

when I add the `-vvv` flag to the command , it verfies that the correct ssh keyfile is being offered to the server:

```
...
...
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_my_rsa RSA SHA256:UXXXXXXXXUx/w1dY explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_my_rsa RSA SHA256:UGKOXXXXXXXXXx/w1dY explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
username@123.456.789.12: Permission denied (publickey).
```

**STRANGENESS:**

When I replace the above command with this one, that explicitly defines the username, then the same exact keyfile variable works perfectly

```
ssh -p22 -i $connecting_keyfile username@$source_ssh_host
```

**Problem:**

It seems that when I replace the ssh_username with a variable, that ssh-agent managing my passphrase somehow looses the ability to send the passphrase credential

In order to manage my passphrase, I have this in my .bashrc:

```
#Add passphrase to ssh-agent
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/agent-environment"

function start_agent {
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
    ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

and this in my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    User username
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /home/username/.ssh/id_my_rsa
```

Comment: I would surely quote the variables in the `ssh -i` command, although that does not seem the cause of the issue here.

Comment: `shellcheck.net` says the above is correct and yes I have tried quotations in -numerous- ways... didn't help